# What is x, y = func(x, y)

Tags: python

I am very new to python. On one of the tutorial I saw (about Tensorflow) I encourted this wierd notation that I never saw on any other langage.

So can someone explain what this do?

```
train_labels, train_samples = shuffle(train_labels, train_samples)
```

or

What does `x, y = function(x, y)` mean in general.

Comment: `function` returns a `tuple` of 2 objects - which is then immediately unwrapped into 2 variables `x`  & `y`. It's called `unpacking`: https://realpython.com/lessons/tuple-assignment-packing-unpacking/

Comment: In the case of `x, y = function(x, y)`, `function()` returns two variables that will be assigned to `x` and `y` respectively. It's perhaps a confusing example because the two function parameters are also named `x` and `y`, but those have nothing to do with it.

Comment: In your case, `shuffle` seems to return a collection (like a list, or tuple), or something that can be iterated over - whatever it is, it seems to have two items in it, which are then assigned to `train_labels` and `train_samples` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x, y = function(x, y)` is for tuple unpacking. When the function you call returns 2 or more values it will assign the first one to x and the second value to y and so on. See the below example

```
def function():
   return 3, 4

x, y = function()

# x will be set to 3
# y will be set to 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically if the `function()` is defined like below:

```
def function():
    # Do some stubs
    return (1,2) # Or even return 1,2
```

Then it will return `(1,2)` as a tuple

And then if you do `x, y = function()`, it called tuple unpacking. Basically `x` is set to the first element of the tuple (1) and `y` is set to the second one (2).

If the function return more, something like `return (4,5,6)`, you can just use `x,y,z = function()`